# UV Unwrap - random faces chosen to be islands

Tags: uv

I used Ninja Ripper to get a mesh for a dress, but when I unwrapped it in blender, it chose to unwrap random faces of the mesh into their own separate islands. I tried putting seams along the edge of the dress to encourage the program not to do that, but it made no difference. What causes this to happen and how do I fix it?

[image: dress mesh]

[image]

Comment: I can't put my finger on it, but something seems strange about the geometry (at least based what I can see in the picture). Any chance there are some duplicate faces, or sections where an outer face has been "pulled through" an inner face?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: OK, I added the blend using blend-exchange. See below the picture. Also, I thought maybe I caused the problem because I had to flip the normals and set them to faces in order to be able to paint on it. However, when I tried unwrapping the original model that I ripped, it had the exact same issue. Is there a simple way to check for and fix duplicate faces or outer faces being pulled through inner faces, or is that something I would have to do manually face by face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh had disconnected vertices. (For anybody who is interested, it looks like Ninja Ripper simply doesn't connect vertices that go along seams, which is why I was able to get a UV unwrap like the image above with no seams. However, it doesn't find seams perfectly, so you wind up with some faces not attached to anything in the UV editor).

I solved the problem by going to the edit layout, selecting the entire mesh, and using "vertices->merge->merge by distance" to bind all the loose vertices together. Then I manually recreated the seams where I knew they should go.